# Set if error condition for value attribute

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the following template code, I set `value="{{ form.title.value }}"` and it displays as I intended,

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Write Title Later"  value="{{ form.title.value }}">
    </div>
```

[image]

However, in other template, if I set `value="{{ form.username.value }}"`, it display `None`

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Username</label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" value="{{ form.username.value }}"
 name="username" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

I have to set `value="{% if form.username.value %}{{ form.username.value }}{%else%}{%endif%}"`

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Username</label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" value="{% if form.username.value %}{{ form.username.value }}{%else%}{%endif%}"
 name="username" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I cannot figure out what's the difference between the two form templates.

Comment: Well in the first the value is probably the empty string `''`, whereas in the latter the value is `None` I guess, the two are not the same, but you can remove the `if` check, and use a `default` filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python there is a difference between `None`, and the empty string `''`. The empty string is a string with no characters, `None` on the other hand is not a string at all, but you can see it like what in many programming languages would probably be something like `null`.

By default, Django typesets `None` as the string `'None'`, and not as an empty string. You can however use the [**`default_if_none`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) filter:

```
value="{{ form.title.value | default_if_none: '' }}"
```

Here we thus will use the empty string `''` in case the value at the left of the pipe character (`|`) is `None`.